# Convert xml into simple file using xslt unix

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, xslt

I am having one xml file (test.xml) looks like this:

```
<hudson>
<job>
<name>cedge</name> 
</job>
<job>
<name>techM</name> 
</job>
<job>
<name>infy</name> 
</job>
<job>
<name>DevP</name> 
<job>
<name>line</name> 
<nextBuildNumber>14</nextBuildNumber> 
</job>
<job>
<name>ment</name> 
<nextBuildNumber>85</nextBuildNumber> 
</job>
<job>
<name>FreeS</name> 
<nextBuildNumber>96</nextBuildNumber> 
</job>
<job>
<name>test</name> 
</job>
</job>
<job>
<name>Email</name> 
</job>
<job>
<name>investigate</name> 
<nextBuildNumber>26</nextBuildNumber> 
</job>
<job>
<name>Java</name> 
</job>
<job>
<name>Tools</name> 
</job>
</hudson>
```

need output file like:

```
"line" "14"
"ment" "85"
"FreeS" "96"
"investigate" "26"
```

trying with below approch

```
 xsltproc x.xslt test.xml
```

made x.xslt like this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="//job">
"<xsl:value-of select="name"/>" = "<xsl:value-of select="nextBuildNumber"/>"
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

getting only

```
 "investigate" = "26"
```

along with blank values. Not getting data from "job-Devp" tags
any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XSLT doesn't quite produce the output you say you get, as it will also output lines for all `job` elements directly under the root `hudson`, like this..

```
 "cedge" = ""
```

Additionally, when you match the `job` element, you are not continuing processing by selecting any descendant `job` elements of those, so the nested `job` elements do not get picked up.

Probably the easiest thing to do is simply add a template that matches the document node `\` and specifically select all the job elements you need (i.e the ones with `nextBuildNumber`

Try this XSLT

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="text" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//job[nextBuildNumber]" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="job">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:text>" = "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="nextBuildNumber"/>
    <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks @TimC for the reply, Its working :) :) :) 
in my question part there was a "Space" between "value-of select" string in " x.xslt" file. my bad soory for that. I edited the question with correct code.